# Getting unfamiliar error when using terminal command to update database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm a bit in over my head when it comes to using and managing large databases. I run a small startup that uses a PostGreSQL and pgAdmin to administer and query the database, which is housed on Herkou.

Typically, I need to 'pull' and updated version of the database in order for the pgAdmin platform to query. This was all set up and explained to me a few months ago, and since then, things have worked well.

Recently, however, whenever I pull the using the following terminal command:

```
heroku pg:pull <db name> <local db name> --app <app name>
```

I get the following error:

```
heroku-cli: Pulling swimming-****-**** ---> <app name>
createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have absolutely no idea how to fix this, and the person that set it up is long gone.

Comment: What I can say from your error message is that it's trying to connect locally to an instance on port 5432 and can't find it. So either your local instance doesn't run on port 5432 or it needs to be started...